# Как преобразовать временную метку на JS?

Tags: javascript

Например есть метка "1421398800" как получить из неё дату,месяц код?
пишу например data=new Date(1421398800);//получаю Sat Jan 17 1970 13:49:58 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))  вместо Fri, 16 Jan 2015 Как это исправить?

Comment: Для начала нужно сказать- откуда Вы берете эту метку времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас видимо метка в секундах. Домножайте на 1000, Date в js работает с миллисекундами.

Comment: домножил но толку ноль

Comment: @test_q_1 только что в консоли попробовал `new Date(1421398800000);` вывод `Fri Jan 16 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))`

Comment: @test_q_1 ровно на 1000, так как ваше число `1421398800` * 1000 = `1421398800000`